# Eclipse displays an error when I try to implement JOINED inheritance in JPA

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, oracle, jpa

I have the following heirarchy of tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Parent (
    id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    column1 VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE Child (
    id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Parent(id),
    --other columns
);
```

Then I have this heirarchy of classes to map the joined inheritance between these two tables.

```java
@MappedSuperClass
class Base implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="column1")
    protected String column1;

}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy.InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
@Table(name="parent")
class Parent extends Base {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("val")
@Table(name="child")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
class Child extends Parent {

    // other columns
    ...
}
```

Eclipse displays an error in the final class, telling me that it cannot resolve `column1`, which it shouldn't. From what I understood about joined inheritance strategy, it is expected not to have that column. I googled everywhere, and did everything by the book, to no avail.

I want to try and run a test - maybe it's a glitch from Eclipse -, but unfortunately I already has more than 50 tables to work with, with each table having relationships with at least a dozen others - this one depends on information from another 5 tables, each has its own problems for the moment -, so I was hoping for some quick pointers as to where I could have possibly gone wrong.

Thank you very much in advance. :)

**UPDATE**

the error message:

> In implied attribute override "column1", column "COLUMN1" cannot be
>   resolved on table "CHILD".

No more information is given.

Comment: Please show the exact and complete error messages.

Comment: Do you have column1 in child table? the message says that it cannot find column1 in child.

Comment: Based on what I understood, a joined inheritance works in the same way as inheritance between classes; it does not require the column in the parent table to be in the child table. Therefore, this error seems illogical in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what is the problem with this code.

The class `Child` inherits everything from `Parent`, including the `Base` class with its columns definitions - because the `@MappedSuperClass` works with *all* inherited classes.

I tried a different, albeit redundant, approach to solve this problem, by grouping the columns in an `@Embeddable` and embed it in the `Parent` class.

```
@Embeddable
class Base implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="column1")
    protected String column1;

}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy.InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
@Table(name="parent")
class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Embdedded
    private Base base;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("val")
@Table(name="child")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
class Child extends Parent {

    // other columns
    ...
}
```

I say redundant because every time I make a new parent - and in my case, there are many - I'll have to add the `Base` reference.

It may not be a solution, more like a workaround, but it's sufficient for the moment.